# linear-gradiente com Inherit não funciona

Tags: css, css3

Qual o motivo pelo qual o atributo **inherit** não funciona quando associado a propriedade **linear-gradient**?

Exemplo:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, inherit 100%);
```

Observação: código testado em navegadores baseados em -webkit, -moz e -ms.